# When using custom Fonts, is there a way to minimize the size they use?

Tags: android, fonts, apk, filesize

We've added Arial, Arial Italic, Arial Bold, and Georgia Italic - the APK jumped from ~ 500K to > 1.5MB

Is there any way at all to minimize the cost of file size with using custom fonts?

Answer (score 1):

You can always remove the characters that you are not using (for example if the font manages Cyrillic characters and you don't want to provide the corresponding translation) with Font Forge.

Google Web fonts could be another way, they typically make ~100ko and they are compatible with android >= 2.2 (which is all you need anyway).

Comment: That's one way I guess, nothing I can do compression wise, etc? It's a real killer!

Comment: That's dandy, I don't believe they have Arial and Georgia though :( I guess I'll figure out another way :) Thanks!

Comment: No, but depending on what you want to do another typeface might be a good idea (and Roboto is a great default font), Arial may be a little boring since it has been used everywhere. Anonymous pro is a free font (also part of google web font) that you might find interesting.  
I mostly use it for my code (and it has been designed specifically for that), but it is not its only possible use.